# Squaring A Decision Variable in Mosel

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, mosel

in my problem, I want to minimize the sum of the square of a decision variable * LARGE_CONSTANT. The reason for square is to incentivize the solver to spread the decision variable around equally; if I have to use the panic variables, I want to use them equally across the set of locations.

Some code (admittedly not enough to reproduce), follows:

```
declarations  
SITE: set of string  
c_min_panic: array(SITE) of mpvar  
c_max_panic: array(SITE) of mpvar  
end-declarations

! Objectives.
Min_Panicking:= sum(s in SITE) ((c_min_panic(s) * 10000)^2)  
Max_Panicking:= sum(s in SITE) ((c_max_panic(s) * 10000)^2)
```

However, this gives error: Mosel: E-101...Incompatible types for operator (`mpvar' ^` integer' not defined).
Removing the ^ makes the problem work fine.

I am shocked why I can't square this? In fact, I see examples in the documentation that look like successful attempts to square the objective function. For example, Page 186 of the [FICO Xpress User Guide](https://www.msi-jp.com/xpress/learning/square/13-moselug.pdf) seems to do it:

```
! Objective: minimise the total squared distance between all points  
  TotDist:= sum(i,j in RN | i<j) ((x(i)-x(j))^2+(y(i)-y(j))^2
```

What am I missing!! Tearing my hair out  Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet does not show which solver module has been loaded: if it employs the Xpress Optimizer module, that is, starts with a line like

```
uses "mmxprs"
```

you also need to load the module 'mmnl' in order to extend the constraint handling capability of the Mosel language to include quadratic expressions, so

```
uses "mmxprs", "mmnl"
```

Another option would be to load the Xpress Nonlinear module:

```
uses "mmxnlp"
```